#  I would like to know how to create a popOver menu that slides in as a submenu of another popOver menu when user taps on a particular row..?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I would like to know how to create a popOver menu that slides in as a submenu of another popOver menu when user taps on a particular row..?

A popOver contains a list of Items called ingredients. When the user taps on a particular item on the popOver, another popOver should slide from it with the classified list. I know how to create popover but i don't have a clue to create such thing since i am new to iPhone and iPad.
Thanx

I created and My requirement is fulfilled by the following code. But I would like to create the popover like www.opcenterllc.com -> testimonials

This code might not be look efficient. But I tried as much as i could.

-(void)popOverMenu
{

```
    ingrediant=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ingrediant1",@"ingrediant2",@"ingrediant3",@"ingrediant4",@"ingrediant5", nil];

    firstViewController=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
    firstViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(300, 400);
    navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
    popOverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:navigationController];

    tblView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 10.0, 260, 360) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tblView.dataSource=self;
    tblView.delegate=self;
    tblView.autoresizesSubviews=YES;

    UILabel *label1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 3, 120, 40)];
    label1.text=@"Ingredients";
    label1.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    label1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label1.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;

    UIBarButtonItem *rightbar=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:label1];

    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(close:)];

    firstViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=rightbar;
    firstViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=backBarButton;

    [firstViewController.view addSubview:tblView];

    [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:Button.frame inView:scrollView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

}

and in

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        UITableViewCell *tblView2=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

```
   secondViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(300, 400);  
   [[secondViewController navigationItem]setTitle:@"Classified"];
    UIBarButtonItem *closeButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"close" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
    secondViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=closeButton;

    [secondViewController.view addSubview:tblView2]; 
    [firstViewController.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
    [tblView2 reloadData];
```

}

ARC is enabled in my app.

Comment: Is the effect you are looking for like a tableview in a navigation controller, but all based in a popover? Are you using storyboards?

Comment: No, I am not using storyboard. Now I have achieved it using UINavigationController. But that is not what I exactly wanted. U can see the design that I am looking for in www.opcenterllc.com -> testimonials. Thanx Mike.

Comment: Ah ok. Whilst I would recommend going with Mike Weller's answer (as it is a cleaner UI solution), have you tried calling a new pop over from the action method triggered by tapping the ingredient?

Comment: Give me a hint. If we can do the same using UINavigationController.

Comment: You would have to heavily customise a UINavigationController through subclassing to do what the menu at www.opcenterllc.com does. That's why I recommend embedding a standard UINavigationController in the first pop over, as Mike Weller suggests.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) inside the popover. This will allow you to 'push' new items, causing the standard right-to-left slide-in behaviour that you want.

Comment: I read it differently, Mike.  It looks like a chain of popovers, where you tap on a row and a second popover is created based at **that** cell in the first popover.  It really sounds like he wants some sort of drawer that slides out of the popover (perhaps by doing an animated widening of the popover).  I don't believe either is in line with current Apple UI guidelines.